# How can two different hosts with different public IP can communicate through sockets? [C programming]

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to make a communication between two different hosts (using two different computers in my University). I saw that we only can bind to the socket **local IP addresses**.
So how can I make a communication client/server just by knowing the ip public addresses of the two hosts ?

P.S : I can't have access to the local ip address of the computer of my university. Maybe for security reasons... And a ping between the two hosts with their public ip works properly.

Comment: Aren't you confusing "local IP address" as address of local interface and "local IP address" as address in private network (LAN)? You can `bind()` socket to local interface address but `connect()` to any accessible remote address.

Comment: @dimich when we say local interface I'm thinking to an address in a LAN network, isn't it ?

Comment: You `bind` on the server and `connect` (using the server's IP/port) on the client.

Comment: @dbush but we can bind on the server only with a private address, a local IP address, right?

Comment: Are client and server located in different LANs behind NAT? If yes, you can't connect them directly through sockets. You can either configure port forwarding on one of routers or make NAT hole punching using third host with public IP.

Comment: @dimich All I know is that they're in the same network (by deducing with the mask) and I just have their public IP address

Comment: @ADL92 Then it's not clear what exact problem you have. Please describe topology of the network and what problem you faced with.

Comment: Usually you `bind` with INADDR_ANY, allowing the use of any local ip address on the machine.  For a TCP connection, that machine then does a `listen` (becoming a server) and the other machine does a `connect` to the first machine (no need for a bind on the client end).

Comment: @ChrisDodd can INADDR_ANY also be used to listen on all the local ip addresses of the network of that machine?

Comment: INADDR_ANY is to listen on all the local addresses of the machine on all the networks it is directly connected to.

Comment: @dimich The thing is that it's the network of the university. I guess I can't have the topology of the network. I just want two machines (on a room of the university, and which are in the same network) communicate with each other through socket. When I type a `ip route show` or `ifconfig -a` for example, I just get their public IP

Comment: @ADL92 Sorry, i don't get why do you name their addresses "public".

Comment: @dimich Because when I checked the IP of the hosts, they didn't belonged to the class of private ip (10.x.x.x, 172.x.x.x, 192.x.x.x)

Comment: @ChrisDodd So for example if the machine which is the server has as IP 192.168.1.32 and is binded to INADDR_ANY, and another machine (another host) has as IP 192.168.1.50, (that is the client) it will be able to communicate with the server ?

Comment: @ADL92 Then you can connect client to server as usual: bind() to `INADDR_ANY` on server and connect() to it from client.

Comment: Those are private IPs, not public IPs (so private to one LAN usually), but if they're on the same lan that would work.  the client on 192.168.1.50 just needs to connect to 192.168.1.32 (and need to specify the port number, which needs to be consistent between the server's bind and the client's connect)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Okay, so now it works the same way with public ips on the same network?

Comment: If the two machines can ping each other's IP addresses, then they *should* be able to make TCP connections to each other as well.  If you find that they cannot, then the likely explanation is that either something between them (e.g. a firewall) is blocking the TCP packets, or that there is a bug in the software you are using to make the connection.  To figure out which it is, you might try using some known-to-be-functional program like `netcat` to make a test TCP connection from one machine to the other (and vice-versa) -- if netcat can't do it, that suggests a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect to the other host without tweaking the router.

```
[Host A Client] -- [Router A] -- (Internet) -- [Router B] -- [Host B Server]
```

`Router B` needs to know how to forward incoming packets to `Host B`, it's done by one of the following:

- Demilitarized Zone
- Static port forwarding
- Dynamic port forwarding
- Universal Plug & Play (NAT-PMP)

Comment: If the machines have public IPs, then by definition, the routers are configured to allow access to those IPs.  That's what "public" means.  If the router is not configured to make the IP public, then its not public.

Comment: Yeah, but, I'm talking about the port forwarding, you need to tweak the router to allow that in all cases.